# Appium Android: How to click on Spannable Text?

Tags: automated-testing, appium, android

just posting the same question posted on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77614973/appium-android-how-to-click-on-spannable-text

I have a screen that contains a `TextView`, the text view text is composed of a `SpannableStringBuilder` which in turn appends a `URLSpan`.

I'd like to write an Appium test to click on that specific `URLSpan` part of the text
.

Searching online has led me to solutions that include tapping on specific coordinates, like this [one](https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-can-i-click-on-text-link-inside-of-textview-android/11067/24).

I'm looking for a more reliable solution if possible, I've tried APIs such as `AppiumBy.linkText` and `AppiumBy.partialLinkText` but without success.

Also the testing project has the capability `UiAutomator2` only. I can imagine that it can be achieved with the Espresso capability as well, but really would like to find a solution with the `UiAutomator` capability only if possible.

Thank you